# how to get probability of each topic in mallet

Tags: mallet

I am doing topic modelling with mallet.I have imported my file(each document in a line)and I trained mallet with 200 topics.Now I have 200 topics with words related to them for each topic.Now I need to know each topic`s probability.How can I know?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The command `bin/mallet train-topics` has an option `--output-doc-topics topic-composition.txt`. This outputs a big table in TAB-separated text format containing the topic composition of each text.